# How to find phase as a function of time from the time derivative of frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency

How is the the time derivative of frequency as a function of frequency, $\dfrac{dfreq}{dt} = F(freq(t))$, related to phase as a function of time, $\phi(t)$? Given the time derivative of frequency, how can I find the phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a chirp:

$$A(t) = A_0\exp(i(\omega_0 + \frac 1 2\alpha t)t) $$

The phase is:

$$ \phi(t)=\omega_0 t + \frac 1 2 \alpha t^2 $$

The frequency is the time derivative of phase:

$$ \omega(t) = \frac d {dt}\phi(t)=\omega_0+\alpha t $$

which is called a chirp because it's a rising frequency (for $\alpha > 0$).

From that, you can see:

$$ \phi(t) = \int_o^t{\omega(t')dt'}$$

which is generally the case.

Applying that to a plane wave:

$$ \omega(t) = \omega_0 $$

gives:

$$ \phi(t) = \omega_0 t + \phi_o $$

where $\phi_0$, the integration constant, becomes an arbitrary phase factor $\exp{(i\phi_0)}$ in the plane wave:

$$ A(t) = A_0 \exp{i(\omega t + \phi_0)}$$